# I need a VB script that executes to update Time Server every time Windows starts up

Tags: windows-7, script, automation, vbscript, date-time

I need the script to automate Time Server update. I suspect the internal battery that keeps time up-to-date is dead and I don't want to change the battery because I'll discard the laptop soon for a new one.

Every time i start-up, I must - Right-click > Adjust date/time (Taskbar) > Internet Time Setting > "Synchronize with an internet time server" and click "Update now" to update the time. Once updated, the time runs correctly throughout because I edited the number of SpecialPollInterval in the registry to poll time server every 660 seconds.

Could someone please give me a VB script and how to use it. Or if there's another way possible, let me know. I'm tired of doing this manually in each Startup and sometimes I do forget, only to be reminded after a software stops working due to the wrong time. The worse is to send outdated emails.

Thanks.

Comment: "Plz give me teh codez" questions are discouraged on Stack Exchange.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142870/possible-new-close-reason-overt-request-for-code

Comment: Sorry I'm new here. I only tried to explain my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a VB script you can just use .bat file with a windows command you can also start from command prompt manually

```
w32tm /resync
```

just put the above command in .bat file and put that file in your start up folder.

1. make a new text file lets say, sync_time.txt and put that command in it
2. rename the .txt file to .bat so you that you have a sync_time.bat file
3. either start that file manually or put it in startup folder so it starts automatically every time you log on.

Comment: I've done exactly what you instructed. I'll back here give feedback on whether it worked or not. But I believe will work.

Comment: It didn't work and double-clicking on the bat file didn't work either.

Comment: try right click bat file (or right click cmd and select runa as administrator and then do w32tm /resync command) and run as Administrator, also you can put the bat file in task scheduler mark Run with highest privileges, and on triggers select run at startup to automate it

Comment: Ran the bat as admin, it didn't work.
Ran CMD as admin got this; 
 
'code C:\Windows\system32>w32tm /resync Sending resync command to local computer The computer did not resync because the required time change was too big. C:\Windows\system32>'

Comment: Please "'code" and "'" not a part of it.

Comment: https://sazwqa.wordpress.com/2008/05/24/the-computer-did-not-resync-because-the-required-time-change-was-too-big/ you can try to copy the code from this page in reg file and run it, it should increase the time difference that is allowed for resyncing

Comment: After installing the reg file in the link you provided, I double clicked the bat file and it worked! It successfully corrected my computer time. Great!! :)
I will now set time wrong to check if it will work on computer restart. I will give feedback in minutes.

Comment: It worked!! @Alen, thank you so much! Now I don't need to worry about time again! Thank you everyone.
Is it proper to ask another question here or open another thread?

Comment: i suggest opening a new thread

Comment: Didn't last long before I started losing time. Lost about 4 hrs.

Comment: If you go down the task scheduler route you can have windows sync the time at startup and then hourly thereafter. The task already exists, you just need to tinker with the interval(s) at which it occurs.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 time sync is a scheduled task. If you start up the task scheduler you can adjust the task so that it runs at start up in addition to the already scheduled updates. You can access task scheduler via control panel, administrative tools.

Comment: I'll try your solution if the one I'm trying now doesn't work. Thank you.